# easyAutocomplete и поиск по вложенностям

Tags: javascript

Использую [easyAutocomplete](http://easyautocomplete.com/). Есть вот массив такой структуры:

```
array(
 0 => array(
    "TYPE" => 1,
    "NAME" => "Иван",
    "LIST" => array(
        0 => array(
               "CITY_NAME" => "Ростов",
               "ADDRESS" => "Улица блабла",
             ),
        1 => array(
               "CITY_NAME" => "Ростов2",
               "ADDRESS" => "Улица блабла2",
             ),
     ),
  )
);

...
```

Суть в том, поиск работает, если я укажу, что искать в NAME.

```
это можно сделать либо так
getValue: "NAME",
либо сделать так
getValue: function(element) {
    return element.NAME;
},
```

Оба этих варианта прекрасно ищут в NAME. Но как заставить easyAutocomplete eqnb искать в массив LIST по полям CITY_NAME и ADDRESS, если в NAME ничего не найдено?

Если кто знает буду признателен. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

ВАЖНО

это только автокомплит, никакой связанности тут нет.

```js
const DATA = Array.from({ length: 5, }, genData);
q: {
    const set = new Set();
    DATA.forEach(el => { set.add('' + el.TYPE); });
    const data = Array.from(set);
    $(".TYPE").easyAutocomplete({ data });
}
q: {
    const set = new Set();
    DATA.forEach(el => { set.add(el.NAME); });
    const data = Array.from(set);
    $(".NAME").easyAutocomplete({ data });
}
q: {
    const set = new Set();
    DATA.forEach(el => { el.LIST.forEach(q => { set.add(q.CITY_NAME); }); });
    const data = Array.from(set);
    $(".CITY_NAME").easyAutocomplete({ data });
}
q: {
    const set = new Set();
    DATA.forEach(el => { el.LIST.forEach(q => { set.add(q.ADDRESS); }); });
    const data = Array.from(set);
    $(".ADDRESS").easyAutocomplete({ data });
}
q: {
    // и т.д. и т.п.
}
q: {
    const set = new Set();
    DATA.forEach(el => { set.add(el.NAME); });
    DATA.forEach(el => { el.LIST.forEach(q => { set.add(q.ADDRESS); }); });
    const data = Array.from(set);
    $(".ALL").easyAutocomplete({ data });
}
function genData(q, i, arr) {
    return {
        "TYPE": i,
        "NAME": 'Иван ' + i,
        "LIST": [
            {
                "CITY_NAME": 'Ростов',
                "ADDRESS": 'Улица блабла',
            },
            {
                "CITY_NAME": 'Ростов2',
                "ADDRESS": 'Улица блабла2',
            }
        ]
    };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/easy-autocomplete/1.3.5/jquery.easy-autocomplete.min.js"></script>



TYPE<br/>
<input class="el TYPE" />
NAME<br/>
<input class="el NAME" />
CITY_NAME<br/>
<input class="el CITY_NAME" />
ADDRESS<br/>
<input class="el ADDRESS" />

всё вместе<br/>
<input class="el ALL" />
```

Comment: А один инпутом то нельзя реализовать?

Comment: используя эту библиотеку - нет

Comment: хотяя, их можно просто свалить в кучу в один `data`, возможно я не понимаю что вам нужно

Comment: @bob7855bob, добавил в ответ

Comment: спасибо. Правда не ищет по всей глубине вложенности, но я допилю. Спасибо.